# app that will turn off the computer if one of the components exceed the suggested temperature

Tags: windows-7, cpu, monitoring, temperature

do you know of any app that will automatically turn off the computer if one of the components exceed the suggested temperature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some BIOS have a built-in shut down function, have you looked there? [CPU Thermometer](http://cpu-thermometer.software.informer.com/1.0/) is a freeware app that will give you a warning or shut down your computer if the CPU reaches a certain temperature.